# R hangs when running the sapply function

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` in the following form:

```
 v2          v3
2.3  c(1,5,8,2)
1.2  c(2,4,3,2)
```

The `typeof(df$v3[1])` is `list`, and I want to convert it to vector. So I write a `sapply`` function and run it:

```
df$v3 <- sapply(
      df$v3,
      function(x) {x <- unlist(x)}
)
```

But it just keeps running and does not generate any result. I also tried `lapply` but it can't give me the expected result. Instead, it again generates a list.

Any my `dput(droplevels(head(df)))` result is :

```
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))), .Names = c("V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102010578>, class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Could you please tell me how to solve it?

EDIT:

I run the `df$V3 <- unlist(df$V3)` for a long time. But the type is still list and a warning is generated:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 496450000 items to be assigned to 99290 items of column 'V3' (496350710 unused)
2: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'list' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 99290 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'list' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
```

Comment: Please show the dput of the dataset showed. i.e. `dput(droplevels(df))`.  If we need to `unlist`, just do `unlist(df$v3)`

Comment: @akrun I tried unlist() directly and the same problem happens. It just keep running. Indeed there are nearly 100,000 rows in the data frame.

Comment: That is why we need the dput of a small data like you showed in the post.

Comment: @akrun When I run dput(droplevels(df)) directly, same thing happens......

Comment: Just do it on a small dataset, `dput(droplevels(head(df)))`  If you have a really big dataset, it is possible that `unlist` could take some time to complete.

Comment: @akrun The result is generated: `.Names = c("V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-99290L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102010578>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))`

Comment: Looks like you have a data.table.  Please update the post with the full `dput` output

Comment: The dput output you showed is not full.  Please don't do the `dput` on the entire dataset, instead just do `dput(droplevels(head(df)))`

Comment: @akrun Does it mean that the V2 is data able and v3 is data frame? So how should I solve this problem?

Comment: There is some miscommunication.  I meant to show the `dput` of the first 6 lines of dataset i.e. `head(df)`

Comment: @akrun I knew. Indeed V3 is a long sparse vector with 5000 elements. I renew the result above and given the number string is too long, I omit part of them

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but it seems like the output you showed is not from the beginning.

Comment: @akrun it is. Because of the length of list, it omit some automatically.

Comment: TRy `dput(droplevels(head(df$V3)))`

Comment: @akrun `Error in UseMethod("droplevels") : 
  no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "list"` ...........

Comment: Ok, then, can you try with `dput(head(df$V3))`

Comment: @akrun This time a long list is printed: `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))`

Comment: @akrun I edited my question.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to comment.  As you showed a small portion of the dput, I can't copy and paste it to test.